# Creating dependent picklist on flows

Tags: flow, dependent-picklist

In Flows, is it possible to create a dependent picklist inside one screen with out using two screens?

ex:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

So far I know we need to use two screens as of now. Guess it is limitation as of now. You can vote this idea, if that is your problem. https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000hqtrAAA

Comment: Thank you. Seems like the only solution up to now is to go for two screens

Comment: It looks like the idea only keeps the picklist values in sync between a Salesforce picklist and the variable picklist values. Does anyone have any insight how to do a controlling picklist with 1 screen?

Comment: Still requires 2 screens as even though an existing picklist set of values can be surfaced in the Flow I've not found it supporting the dependencies. http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_picklist.htm

Comment: We have just provided a solution for this. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

We've published an unofficial Flow Screen Component that solves this problem. Learn more about it here:
https://medium.com/@alexedelstein/dependentpicklists-a-flow-screen-component-c97dcee1796

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce has also published a Flow Component (Lightning-only) for dependent picklists in Winter '19:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=vpm_designer_elements_screen_dependentpicklists.htm&type=0

Unfortunately it doesn't support dependent multi-select picklists as of yet..

Answer (score 0):

Flow does not support dependent picklist because at the time you select the value of the field the flow screen is not refreshed. so we use the new screen for populate the value.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a standard flow component for dependent picklists as of Winter '19.
Check out this video on how to create a dependent picklist.
https://youtu.be/FSQ52gVOgcY

Salesforce Documentation 
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_ref_elements_screencmp_dependentpicklists.htm&type=5 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_designer_elements_screen_dependentpicklists.htm